# Calculating time span between two date values in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, date, datagridview, timespan

I have 2 date columns in a `DataGridView` populated with dates. I need to calculate the `time span` between these dates and display them when the user clicks on that particular row. I read up the `timespan` structure and found that it uses the format `#date2# - #date1#`. Here is the relevant code in my program:

```
Dim Timespan span
span = FaultsDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value - FaultsDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value
```

The date in the 5th(Index 4) column is always AFTER the ones in the 4th(Index 3) column. I have made sure of this. However, I get an `ArgumentOutOfRange Exception` with the following message:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You either have 0 rows or not enough columns. Your best option is to work against the underlying data object, not accessing grid cells directly. Code like this is very easy to break: `.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4)`.

Comment: you possibly have no SELECTED rows

Comment: I looked at the values right before this calculation, and it gave me datetime values of '12/7/2014 7:58:00 PM' and '12/7/2014 6:58:00 PM'. Pretty sure there are selected rows. Neolisk, can you please explain to me the vulnerability of this code? Really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it, guys. Found this on an MS forum - (DirectCast(FaultsDataGridView(4, e.Row.Index).Value, DateTime). This works, but I don't exactly know the difference. The datatype was datetime already.

Answer (score 0):

Use (DirectCast(DataGridView([columnindex], e.Row.Index).Value, DateTime). Thanks a lot for your inputs, guys.